# Angular JS Unit Testcases for ng-show using Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

How to write for unit testcases for ng-show?

```
<div class="fulldiv">
<div class="title-left">Establishment ID: <span>*</span></div>
<div class="input-right">
<input type="text" name="establishmentid" value="" ng-model="establishmentid" ng-maxlength="20" required>
<span ng-show="updatesiteform.establishmentid.$error.pattern">
    Invalid establishmentid.
</span>
</div>
```

And this is my unit testcase for validating the field

I wanted to ensure the right validation message is displayed..how to do that?

```
    it('with a length of 1', function () {
        //expect(form).toBeUndefined();
        form.establishmentid.$setViewValue('1');
        $scope.$digest();
        expect(form.establishmentid.$valid).toBe(true);

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be checking for a true or truthy value on the same value that you are using to show the message.

```
it('with a length of 1', function () {
    form.establishmentid.$setViewValue('1');
    $scope.$digest();
    expect(updatesiteform.establishmentid.$error.pattern).toBe(true);
});
```

You can also check for the right error message in an end-to-end test using Protractor.